# How to create uml class diagram and notations by programming?

Tags: uml, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gmf

```
Package model = UMLFactory.eINSTANCE.createPackage();
model.setName("MyPackage");
Class cls = model.createOwnedClass("MyClass", false);
```

I created some uml2 models by code above, now I want to create a class diagram and some notations for package/class etc.  How can I do this by programming?  (We can initialize class diagram for .uml by uml2tools in eclipse, but what's the API for it?)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I found org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.core.commands.CreateDiagramCommand, and org.eclipse.uml2.diagram.component.edit.commands.ClassDiagramNotationClassCreateCommand,
should I use them to create diagram and class notation?
any comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The uml2 model provides you with the entities needed to create uml models. UML diagrams are views of these models and are not part of the mode definition. So you can't create a diagram :-(